# How does speechify progressively create audio chunks and display it as one audio file?

Tags: node.js, react-native, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, amazon-polly

I am unable to figure out the method in which [Speechify](https://speechify.com) is turning their text chunks into audio, and then playing it on my phone as if it is one large mp3 file. I am able to play each audio chunk separately and have it play while my ios app is in the background. But somehow Speechify is chunking these audio bits together and offering lock screen controls with an estimated time duration. Any ideas on how they are doing this? Are they streaming from the device to a local url?

Just for some background, Speechify takes text and turns it into mp3 audio. It does this by sending individual sentences as the reader progresses and getting back the base64 encoded mp3 audio chunk. It preloads about 2-3 sentences ahead.

I am using react-native for my frontend and Node + Express for backend. I am using amazon polly to generate the individual audio chunks for sentences. I am trying to mesh these audio chunks together so from the lockscreen it says there is one long file playing, not keep skipping to the next audio track/chunk.